# pandas consolidate multiple excel by worksheet into individual excel files

Tags: python, pandas

I have many excel files, each of them have 3 worksheets(i.e. sheets) I want to consolidate sheet1 of every excel files into a consolidated file, similarly I would like to consolidate Sheet2 and Sheet3 into separate consolidated files, I tried to do it as below;

```
for tabs in ["memory","cpu","storage"]: # these are common worksheet names
    filenames = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(file))
    print(filenames)
    concatDf = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(open(f, 'rb',sheet_name=tabs, error_bad_lines=False, encoding="latin1")) for f in filenames])
    concatDf.to_csv(str(tabs) + "_" + "consolidated.csv", index=True)
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself, felt this would be useful for many pandas users working with excel files. what this does is, it consolidates worksheets by name across all the excel files (in the example below, there are 3 work sheet["memory","cpu","storage"]) in each excel files, that are to be consolidated, it generates consolidated excel files by worksheet names, in the example below it would generate 3 consolidated excel files

```
os.chdir(dir path)

for tabs in ["memory","cpu","storage"]:# list contains worksheet names
    file = "xls"
    filenames = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(file))
    print(filenames)
    concatDf = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name=tabs) for f in filenames])
    concatDf.to_csv(str(tabs) + "_" + "consolidated.csv", index=True)
```